# Simulation Editor Blender 2.90

Tags: node-editor, particles, experimental-features

In the developer tools experimental features for blender 2.9, there is a box that says "New Particle System". When I check it, it allows me to access the "Simulation Editor", which seems to be a type of particle nodes. I have looked online for information about this, but I have not found any. Can anyone explain how to use this "Simulation Editor" or tell me where I can find more out about it?

To clarify: this is NOT the functions branch, this is just developer tools for Blender 2.9.

Comment: Part of *Everything Nodes* project: https://developer.blender.org/T67088 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQi2BqlQtnI (basically a better/real implementation of animation nodes: https://code.blender.org/2016/03/proposal-for-caching-nodes-and-physics-development-in-blender-2-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the system was removed... for now. https://developer.blender.org/rBM7254